# Scroll speed on mac trackpad is too fast

Tags: jquery, macos, scroll

I am using jQuery.scrollSpeed on my site to controll the scroll speed of the website.

It works fine on all devices except when it comes to scrolling on a mac trackpad the scroll speed is just too fast, on one scroll it jumps to the next section of the page. Is there anything I can do about this?

Reference link - [joblessinc.com](http://joblessinc.com/)

Answer (score 0):

May be Smooth Scroll is enabled on your website from Ultimate Addons dashboard page – disable it.

If the above does not help, navigate to Appearance > Customize > Body (section) and disable Smooth Scroll from there as well.